# How to convert nested list into list containing strings in python?

Tags: python

I was trying to read a csv file:

```
SigGenelist = []
Sig = csv.reader(open('Genelist.csv'))
for row in Sig:
    SigGenelist.append(row)
print (SigGenelist)
```

the print out was like:

```
[['x'], ['0610010K14Rik'], ['0610011F06Rik'], ['1110032F04Rik'], ['1110034G24Rik'], ...
```

so I got a nested list, but I would like to have a list with each element as string, something like:

```
['x', '0610010K14Rik', '0610011F06Rik', '1110032F04Rik', '1110034G24Rik', ...
```

I tried to convert element into string like:

```
SigGenelist = []
Sig = csv.reader(open('Genelist.csv'))
for row in Sig:
    row = str(row) # try to change row into string instead of list
    SigGenelist.append(row)
print (SigGenelist)
```

but did not get what I would like to...

```
["['x']", "['0610010K14Rik']", "['0610011F06Rik']", "['1110032F04Rik']","['1110034G24Rik']"...
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Be sure to mark an answer as "accepted"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `append` try using `+` operator, change your line

```
...
SigGenelist.append(row)
...
```

to use `+=`:

```
...
SigGenelist += row
...
```

[Append](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html?#array.array.append) is used to add a single element to your list, while += and [extend](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html?#array.array.extend) is used to copy the list on the right hand side to the left hand side. And since extend is more expensive due to an additional function call (not that it matters, difference is very small), += is a good way in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my_list = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
print [item for sublist in my_list for item in sublist]
```

This is a list comprehension that will flatten a list of lists into a single list.

Or, maybe the simpler option is not appending, but adding the rows to the list.

```
SigGenelist = []
Sig = csv.reader(open('Genelist.csv'))
for row in Sig:
    SigGenelist += row
print (SigGenelist)
```

`.append` will add the entire list to the end of the list, resulting in the nested lists. `+=` will just concatenate the lists, making it a list of depth 1!

Comment: Sorry that I did not realize that I could "accept answer" it seemed I could only accept one. But I gave a up vote for your answer. Thanks for the answer and explanation.

Comment: No problem! You should always accept the one that answers it the best, and umotto did it very succinctly!

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

`SigGenelist.append(row)`

To this:

`SigGenelist.extend(row)`

Answer (score 1):

This might be idiomatic:

```
from itertools import chain
csv_reader = csv.reader(open('Genelist.csv'))
SigGeneList = list(chain.from_iterable(csv_reader))
```

Comment: Not sure I messed up something or not, but it did not work out for me...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sum` builtin function, since `csv.reader` returns a generator, the following code will do the job:

```
Sig = csv.reader(open('Genelist.csv'))
SigGenelist = sum(Sig, [])
```

Comment: Basically, it worked like other methods, but somehow the first element would not be in the new list...`['x', '0610010K14Rik', '0610011F06Rik', '1110032F04Rik', '1110034G24Rik', ...]` I only got  `['0610010K14Rik', '0610011F06Rik', '1110032F04Rik', '1110034G24Rik', ...]`, not sure I did not mess up with something... though

Comment: the `sum(generator, [])` is a code snipet I use often. I'm sure there is some code in the middle making some noise.

Comment: All solutions seem equal, but you should use the one that is faster and uses less memory. Furthermore, you should also look for readability. Compare the `for` loops, and initializating a list outside the loop  with the "one liners", which one is easier to read? which one has less chances to let you introduce a bug? In this case, I prefer to have the work done in just one line. And from all the other oneliners, I think the option I suggest is the most clear and easy to read, and does not require any other library import. I wouldn't be posting another answer If I thought the others are equal.

Comment: I have tried in this way: `#    SigGenelist.extend(row)
#    SigGenelist += row
    SigGenelist = sum((row for row in Sig), [])` I tried each solution by commenting out other two, `sum()` was almost good except there was no 'x' in the result list. I am quite a beginner,  could not figure out why. But eager to learn, any idea please let me know.

Comment: You should only execute the two lines in my answer. If you add some extra code in the middle that extract an element of `Sig` generator, you lose the first item, namely, the 'x'. In fact, I think that directly doing:    `SigGenelist = sum(Sig, [])` should work too.

Comment: Yes, they worked.`SigGenelist = sum((row for row in Sig), [])`, `SigGenelist = sum(Sig, [])`, apologize that I messed it up. Thank you for answer and explanation. (no idea why I could not cast a up vote for your answer...)

Comment: No need to apology, mi friend :) Great to meet good people with good intentions like you. The point I wanted to made is that there is a big difference between a for loop and a simple line like `SigGenelist = sum(Sig, [])`. They are probably semantically equivalent, but the `sum` option is  simpler, easy to read, and is harder to introduce bugs in that way.